# What recourse is available when a country's entry requirements change between flight ticket purchase and travel?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, insurance

On February 2 2020 the Philippines announced it would deny entry to all non-Filipinos entering via China, Macau & Hong Kong with immediate effect, in an attempt to control the spread of the 2019-nCoV virus.

Given a LGW-HKG-MNL flight itinerary with Cathay Pacific, and Cathay Pacific refusing refunds and only allowing rerouting via CX cities:

> Rebooking/ rerouting charges will be waived on conditions that:
>
> - Rerouting to/from/via Cathay Pacific/ Cathay Dragon online cities

As the flights have not been cancelled (which would make it Cathay Pacific's problem), it appears to be impossible to get to Manila without purchasing a new ticket with a different carrier (or rebooking for some time in the future).

I can understand that it is not Cathay Pacific's responsibility to get a passenger to their destination if they fail to meet the entry requirements.

Is a post-booking change of entry requirements typically covered by travel insurance? Without travel insurance, is there any other recourse available?

Comment: Have you called Cathay?  Customer service may be able to do more than the T&C requires them to.

Comment: I guess this should count as "medical reasons" which are normally covered by travel insurance?

Comment: @gerrit my travel insurance covers cancellation for medical reasons, defined as being when a trip must be cancelled due to serious injury or unexpected severe illness (in rather longer legalese). The exact definition probably varies from one insurer to the next, but I'd be extremely surprised if any of them cover "the destination country is scared that I or somebody else from my departure point might be sick". That's not to say other aspects of travel insurance wouldn't cover it, although I don't immediately see any part of my policy which is obviously applicable.

Comment: @gerrit My travel insurance also restricts cancellation coverage due to medical reasons to situations where *I* experience an unexpected and serious medical condition preventing *me* from travelling. I doubt that any travel insurance will cover loss caused by changes in immigration rules, no matter what the exact reason is for the changes.